# How to Limit React Multi-Checkbox Item Selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my checkbox components for multi selection.

```js
const MultiselectCheckbox = ({ options, onChange, limitedCount }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(options);

  const toggle = index => {
    const newData = [...data];
    newData.splice(index, 1, {
      label: data[index].label,
      checked: !data[index].checked
    });
    setData(newData);
    onChange(newData.filter(x => x.checked));
  };

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <label key={item.label}>
          <input
            readOnly
            type="checkbox"
            checked={item.checked || false}
            onClick={() => toggle(index)}
          />
          {item.label}
        </label>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const options = [{ label: 'Item One' }, { label: 'Item Two' }];

ReactDOM.render(
  <MultiselectCheckbox
    options={options}
    onChange={data => {
      console.log(data);
    }}
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I want to limit the items I can choose by putting limitedCount in my code.
props for example

- limitedSelectCount = 1

  - Only one check box can be selected
- limitedSelectCount = n

  - Multiple n check boxes available

Comment: What do you want to do if you reach the limit? Should it disable all other checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

> its very easy just put a condition in your toggle function to check if
> the length of data array is not greater or equal to the limitedCount.  Also
> check if the limitedCount prop has been passed to the component or
> not.

**UPDATE**

> Also just you need to see if the user has checked the option or unchecked the option, so pass a check into toggle function.

```js
const MultiselectCheckbox = ({ options, onChange, limitedCount }) => {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(options);

  const toggle = (check,value) => {
    
    // add below line to code
    if(limitedCount && data.length>=limitedCount && check) return;

    const newData = [...data];
    newData.splice(index, 1, {
      label: data[index].label,
      checked: !data[index].checked
    });
    setData(newData);
    onChange(newData.filter(x => x.checked));
  };

  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item, index) => (
        <label key={item.label}>
          <input
            readOnly
            type="checkbox"
            checked={item.checked || false}
            onClick={(e) => toggle(e.target.checked,index)}
          />
          {item.label}
        </label>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

const options = [{ label: 'Item One' }, { label: 'Item Two' }];

ReactDOM.render(
  <MultiselectCheckbox
    options={options}
    onChange={data => {
      console.log(data);
    }}
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I checked your code but I found a problem.

When the limitedCount condition is entered, nothing can be selected when the count is reached.

It must be switched to another item on a line that does not exceed the limitedCount.

please help me.

Comment: i have updated the code now i think it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition inside the toggle function.

```
const handleOptionSelection = (optionKey: string, isChecked: boolean) => {
  let selectedOptionKeysCopy = [...selectedOptionKeys];

  if (isChecked && selectedOptionKeysCopy.length <= maxSelections) {
    selectedOptionKeysCopy = unique([...selectedOptionKeysCopy, optionKey]);
  } else {
    selectedOptionKeysCopy = selectedOptionKeysCopy.filter(
      (selectedOptionKey) => selectedOptionKey !== optionKey
    );
  }

  onChangeSelected(selectedOptionKeysCopy);
};
```

Here is a [sample for reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-g4pj2e).